# JavaScript: How can I get data from one of my sites and sync it on another

Tags: javascript

I have a [project on GitHub](https://syknapse.github.io/Contribute-To-This-Project/) hosted on GitHub pages that has a simple counter. It counts the number of contributions to the project by counting the number of `.cards` there are on the page. Every time I merge a PR it adds a new card so when the page is loaded it shows the new updated number.

How can I take this number and display it on another not related project? I want to show the current number of contributions to that project on my portfolio, and I want it to be synced with the original (no need for ajax real time, as long as it's the most recent number on load.)

I can't tell if this is a really simple problem or a complex one and so far I have not managed to find any resources to help because I'm not sure what are the correct keywords for this.
I have tried to use a cdn of the js file but that obviously doesn't work because it doesn't find any `.cards` on my portfolio. I have tried to figure out if this is something related to APIs but I have no experience in working with that so I would be grateful If anyone can point me in the right direction before I invest few hours on the wrong track.

Comment: you are the one who made that project on GitHub if yes then do the same work to get the counting number.

Comment: Both projects are mine. But I'm still not sure how to get the number of `.cards` in one project to display in another not related project?

Comment: how do you get the `.cards` in the first project!! Just do the same work and count them !!

Comment: Maybe I'm not explaining myself well or I'm not understanding your answer and it's something obvious. In the first project it is as simple as using `cards.length` to get the current number of cards on the page (which represent the number of contributions to the project). I want this number to be displayed and always stay synced on my portfolio which is a separate project. I can't count the number of `cards` on my portfolio because there are non, I want the number from the Contributions project. I honestly can't visualise how I can do that. Maybe it's staring me in the face!

Comment: if it's impossible to do the same work you have to code a server using anything you want nodejs or php .. and with that server you can render the first project and you can get the number of `.cards `